# Custom JSP Tag issue

Tags: tags, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm getting some unusual exception as below.

```
Sep 26, 2012 12:09:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: <h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for c in /Test.jsp</h3><p>null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.</p><h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for sql in /Test.jsp</h3><p>null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.</p><h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for x in /Test.jsp</h3><p>null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.</p><h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for fmt in /Test.jsp</h3><p>null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.</p>
```

Actually I've implemented a custom tag.

When I used that custom tag using taglib its working fine.

```
<%@taglib prefix="path" uri="PathGenerator"%>
```

But when i started using it with other JSTL tag libs. Its generating the above exception.

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<%@taglib prefix="path" uri="PathGenerator"%>
```

Can anyone please help me.